# Is vaporwave the first global genre that originated online?

Tags: genre, vaporwave

In the video [*Vaporwave: A Brief History of a Genre That No One Has Heard Of*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D88iKeigqd4), the narrator says (from 0:50 to 0:59; my transcription, so might contain mistakes):

> It [the vaporwave genre] distinctively has no set location as to where it originated, as it started online, making it the first genre of music to be completely globalized.

Is this claim about the vaporwave music genre true? Did it really originate online, and if yes, was it really the first global one? (And maybe as of now, the only one?)

Comment: Vapourware was a software genre long before it was a music genre;-) Software promised but never delivered.

Answer (score 6):

Arguably, no. There are other examples like seapunk and [chillwave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillwave):

> [Chillwave] is also a prime example of shifting the idea from defining a musical movement's birth in part by a specific geographic location, as is historically done, to focusing instead on how the groups became linked and defined through various outlets on the Internet.

Chillwave appeared in mid 2000s, while vaporwave emerged in the early 2010s.

Also I'm pretty sure seapunk, witch house and similar "genres" appeared before vaporwave, however one could pinpoint the "originators" of these genres more specifically.